# Cannot login after modifying /etc/environment

Tags: login, sudo, recovery-mode

By mistake I added a line ="" in /etc/environment and now I cannot login in ubuntu anymore. Symptoms:

1. ctrl+alt+f1~f3 to tty: stuck in a login loop.
2. Recovery mode: cannot use **sudo**, and hence cannot modify /etc/environment (although I can view it)
3. normal login: the system is running in low-graphics mode

Comment: Did you mount your file in `rw mode` in recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of "papercut" that has held Linux back for years.  Yes, we can fix it, but we shouldn't even have to waste time on this sort of problem.  But I digress from what you need.

If you cannot login, I'd try these steps in escalation-as-needed order.

1. Boot to [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and attempt your fix.  Success?  Then your done.
2. If that doesn't work, boot to a LiveCD or Bootable USB (e.g., how you installed Ubuntu in the first place).  Mount the partition that contains the problem file, and sudo edit from there.

Provided you have not encrypted your drive, the latter **will** work, but is for the more experienced.

Comment: Booting into RecoveryMode did not work for me as I still couldn't modify the file causing the problem. Booting from a LiveCD and mounting the problematic system did solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

press CTRL+ALT+F3 when login screen apperas.it shows a terminal view.
then login using the credentials.
after login edit /etc/environment file using vim.
if vim not installed install it using sudo apt-get install vim.
now run vim /etc/environment .then press i and edit the changes you have made.then press escape :wq to save changes .then press alt+right arrow until you see login page.if you cant able to edit /etc/environment change permissions by sudo chmod 666 /etc/environment now u can edit.hope it works

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. OP clearly stated "ctrl+alt+f1~f3 to tty: stuck in a login loop". Moreover, you might want to consider adding a bit of formatting to your post.